# PHPStan does can not found functions in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: codeigniter, phpstan

I have an CodeIgniter 4 application, and I am using PHPStan to help me with static analysis. My problem is that PHPStan complain that he can not find the CodeIgniter 4 functions. I check the PHPStan documentation, and I have this phpstan.neon configuration:

```
parameters:
level: 5
paths:
    - app\Models\IonAuthModel.php
scanDirectories:
    - app\config
    - app\controllers
    - app\database
    - app\filters
    - app\helpers
    - app\language
    - app\libraries
    - app\models
    - app\thirdparty
    - app\views
excludePaths:
    - app\models\IonAuthModel.php
    - app\controllers\Auth.php
    - app\controllers\Migrate.php
ignoreErrors:
    - '#Function view not found.#'
    - '#Function base_url not found.#'
    - '#Function redirect not found.#'
    - '#Function config not found.#'
    - '#Function helper not found.#'
```

As you can see I have been forced to add some of the errors in ignoreErrors, but list is growing. Now I have error about the lang method:

```
$output[] = lang($message) !== $message ? lang($message) : '##' . $message . '##';
```

but according to Codeigniter 4, lang method is correctly used here, and PHPStorm has no complain about this method. However, PHPStan gives the error:

Function lang not found.
 Learn more at https://phpstan.org/user-guide/discovering-symbols

But I readed three times the link above and I can stil not resolve the issue with CodeIgniter function not found by PHPStan. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These functions are defined here: https://github.com/codeigniter4/framework/blob/master/system/Common.php

So you'd need to put this file in your project into "discovering symbols"-related config parameters.

Also what might be sufficient to do instead: Put this file https://github.com/codeigniter4/framework/blob/master/system/bootstrap.php into `bootstrapFiles` in your phpstan.neon.

Also there are some old GitHub issues on analysing CodeIgniter projects with PHPStan, check them out, they link some repositories with sample configuration:

- https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan/issues/890
- https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan/issues/2132